# Python (Anaconda Spyder) Turkish Character issue

Tags: python, character, anaconda, spyder, turkish

I have a problem about python 3.5 Turkish character.

You can see issue in pictures. How can I fix this ?

My Codes is below. You can see last row that  `print(blink1.text)`give charcter problem but `print("çÇğĞıİuÜoÖşŞ")`is not problem despite that's all same

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get("http://www.ensonhaber.com/son-dakika")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
for tag in soup.find_all("ul",attrs={"class":"ui-list"}):
    for link1 in tag.find_all('li'):
        for link2 in link1.find_all('a',href=True):
            print("www.ensonhaber.com" + link2['href'])
            print("\n")
            print(link2['title'])
        for link3 in link1.find_all('span',attrs={"class":"spot"}):
            # özet kısmı print(link3.text)
            print("\n")      
            rbodysite = "http://www.ensonhaber.com"+link2['href']
            rbody = requests.get(rbodysite)
            soupbody = BeautifulSoup(rbody.text)
            for btag in soupbody.find_all("article",attrs={"class":""}):
                for blink1 in btag.find_all("p"):
                    print(blink1.text)
                    print("çÇğĞıİuÜoÖşŞ")
```

My output :

```
Hangi Åehirde Ã§ekildiÄi bilinmeyen videoda bir Ã§ocuk, ailesiyle yolculuk yaparken gÃ¶rdÃ¼ÄÃ¼ trafik polisinin Ã¼ÅÃ¼dÃ¼ÄÃ¼nÃ¼ dÃ¼ÅÃ¼nerek gÃ¶zyaÅlarÄ±na boÄuldu. Trafik polisi, yanÄ±na gelen Ã§ocuÄu "Ben Ã¼ÅÃ¼mÃ¼yorum" diyerek teselli etti.
çÇğĞıİuÜoÖşŞ
```

[image: python codes]

[image: character issue]

Comment: Please post your code -- not a screen shot -- and the error -- not a screen shot.  What is the issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (also called SO)! I changed the links to images for you, since you can't post images. Hope you get your answer!

Comment: Çözüm bulabildiniz mi? r.encoding = 'ISO-8859-9'  deniyorum...

Comment: @user564853 veriyi çektiğim siteyi değiştirdim çözüm öyle bulabildim

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most certainly wrong code page. Python is codepage agnostic and neither print nor beautifulsoup is going to fix it for you.

The site seems to serve all pages in UTF-8 so I think your terminal is something else. I don't know what character set has ı but the locations of the corrupted characters and their values suggest Windows-1254. You need to call iconv, but you first need to read the meta tag `<meta charset=` because it won't always be UTF-8. On the other side, you also need to know your terminal's encoding, but that's harder to get.